# Finding the matrix of T with respect to two bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Here's what I'm struggling with:

[image]

Here's what I interpret this as (which may be where my confusion lies):

- The transformation maps bases of $\beta$ to $\beta \prime $.
- This makes sense because it maps bases from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ and that's what linear transforms do, when it comes down to it.
- The matrix of transformation $Mat_{\beta , \beta \prime}(T)$ must contain the linear transformation necessary to translate these bases from $\beta$ to $\beta \prime$.
- Thus, $m_A \vec v = \vec b$ where $\vec v$ and $\vec b$ are basis vectors in $\beta$ and $\beta \prime$ respectively.

However, I've not been able to obtain the matrix of transformation needed from this thought process, and mapping that matrix to column vector $(x,y)$ doesn't give the general transformation given at the top of the question. Where am I going wrong here?